# When is the temporary database used?

Tags: sql-server-2005, collation

I've been told that RDBMS ( SQL Server in this case )  make use of the temporary database to perform its internal job, for instance when a `SELECT count( column ) FROM foo` query is performed.

What kind of queries / statements  trigger the use of the temporary database?

**background:**

We are currently about to change the collation on our application database, but we have been told there might be problems if that database make use of the temporary database, because they will have different collation. The rationale is the temporary database is already being used by other applications.

So we want to identify what kind of queries may trigger temp db usage and see if they'll have any problem.

Comment: Minor quibble. A *temporal* database would be one that deals with date and time ranges in some way Typically, where attributes are relevant only over a specific date or time range. A *temporary* database, which is what you are discussing, is one that is only used for briefly and then the data is discarded.

Comment: Oohh... thank for the note Thomas, I didn't realize I was using a false cognate. In spanish "temporal" actually means "temporary" :) Fixing it

Answer (score 0):

I've found this about when is the db used:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx